# archunit - navigate from JavaType to corresponding JavaClasss

Tags: java, archunit

How am I supposed to navigate from a JavaType instance in archunit to the corresponding JavaClass? I need to check if a method return type is primitive but JavaMethod.getJavaType() returns a JavaType that offers no means to check if the return type is primitive.

Comment: By the way: You could also directly use [`.getRawReturnType()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaCodeUnit.html#getRawReturnType()) on your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested in generic type information, you can use [`javaType.toErasure()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaType.html#toErasure()) to navigate to the corresponding `JavaClass`.

Comment: Thanks, for now generic type information does not matter to me.